# Java GUI Dynamically add buttons

Tags: java, user-interface, dynamic, dynamically-generated

I'm implementing a GUI for a game (Qwirkle) which does not have a fixed board size. It dynamically grows when placing tiles next to another tile (with same color or shape).

Basically, I have an x,y-plane which grows dynamically when placing tiles. I have a function which gives the the bounds in an array[4] (left, top, right, bottom) such that I know what I have to display in the GUI.

Now I'm looking for a way to update the GUI's x,y-plane everytime new tiles are placed. Every tile is represented as a button and can be selected when the button is empty (meaning the empty tile, or no tile).

So if a tile (x,y) is placed ((0,0) initially), I want a x,y-plane with from -1 to 1 (fot both x and y). Then when a tile is placed on (1,0), the (x,y)-plane should be updated with new bounds. Preferably buttons should be a square (so a GridLayout might not be a good option?). So I have a fixed Jpanel in which the x,y-plane is centered and expands dynamically.

Any ideas how to display such a game?

[Qwirkle (idea of how tiles can be placed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ9lR.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Null layout (setLayout(null)) and manipulate the location using setBounds.